# jQuery - Wrap specific parts of a textual element

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

Here is my HTML sample:

```html
<td class="prod ">
  ACTIVE_server
  <br/> inactivename_1
  <br/> inactivename_2
  <br/> inactivename_3
  <br/>
</td>
```

I just want to wrap inactive data with dedicated span.
something like this:

```html
<td class="prod ">
  ACTIVE_server
  <br/>
  <span class="inactive">
           inactivename_1
           <br/>
           inactivename_2
           <br/>
           inactivename_3
           <br/>
       </span>
</td>
```

I've tried a couple of things like these:

```js
$('td[class*="prod"]>br').after('<span id="inactiveServer">');

$('td[class*="prod"]>br').wrap('<span id="inactiveServer">');

$('td[class*="prod"]>br').nextUntil('<br>').wrapAll('<span class="inactiveServer">');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="prod ">
  ACTIVE_server
  <br/> inactivename_1
  <br/> inactivename_2
  <br/> inactivename_3
  <br/>
</td>
```

but unfortunately, it doesn't work at all. How to make it work?

Comment: Please write an example of active and inactive data.

Comment: @MichaelMalinovskij those are just server names which are listed in a table. I have to implement a button which hides the inactive ones, in order to make a clearer view on the table

Comment: Just wrap each server in an separate span, it'll be much easier to select and then wrapAll(). Custom filter() function would help with selection help.

Comment: ok i tried to wrap each server using `$('td[class*="prod"]>br').wrap('<span class="inactiveServer">');`
unfortunately, it warps **<br/>** elements only.

Comment: I mean wrapping each string while the table is rendering.
Now you have structure like this `"text1<br>text2<br>"`, change it to `<span>text1</span><span>text2</span>`. And set `display: block` to spans. After that - selecting and wrapping part of `td` content would be a piece of cake. If this structure is acceptable for you - I'll write the answer that will work for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `contents` and `filter` method:

```
$('td.prod').contents().filter(function(i){
    if (i > 1) return this
}).wrapAll('<span class="inactiveServer"/>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YuZUp/

As @wirey correctly suggests you can also use the `slice` method;

```
$('p.prod').contents().slice(1).wrapAll('<span class="inactiveServer"/>');
```